# Using ngrok + wordpress hosted on localhost

Tags: wordpress, localhost, ngrok

I am hosting a site from my PC at home and want to host a wordpress site on it . I am using ngrok so that people would be able to access my site from outside . Now the problem is whenever i open the site it opens perfect until i go to /wp-admin . It redirects to localhost and thats it it wont work now . How do i solve it ? I have tried all given on stackoverflow and in the docs but none worked for me . Would be nice if someone could tell me the solution

Comment: You need rename you siteurl in database on your ngrok URL.

Comment: Is there any good reason to do this? Paying for energy and internet that needs to run at home, and paying for unlimited ngrok ressources might be more expensive that running your blog on any low-cost hoster

Comment: Open your active site database -> wp_options.php table and change you search site_url, home_url and replace or add your current domain name

Comment: Hi, try calling ngrok with this.

ngrok http 80 --host-header=rewrite